# What appropriate amount of tzedakah for mi sheberech?

Tags: synagogue, tzedakah-charity, torah-service, choleh-sick, social-convention

What is considered to be appropriate amount to give for mi shebereh asking for a blessing for an individual ill person?

Comment: Andrei, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing this question here! I hope you'll look around the site and find other material of interest to you, perhaps starting with our 79 other [tag:tzedakah-charity] questions.

Comment: something that hurts. i.e. it depends on your means.

Answer (score -1):

If you can afford it, his hospital or medical deductible.

Comment: who says this?  It seems a bit much for a mishaberach.

Comment: Never heard this before. Source?

Comment: It's not a requirement but a derech chassidus. Generally, I have not seen or heard of any donation publicly announced or requested for mi sheberach - it's not like an aliyah. If you want to donate to the shul, donate privately what you feel. My own opinion, donate directly to something that directly assists the sick person. That helps more than donating to the shul.

Comment: @Dan, could you [edit] your answer to add the reasoning in your comment (and any other support you have)?  Thanks.